# Parse query not fetching ParseObject's related ParseUser

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have my class `Article` with a `ParseRelation` with the class `User` called `idUser`.

When I fetch the artlices list with `Parse.Query`:

```
var articles = Parse.Object.extend("Article");
var query = new Parse.Query(articles);
query.descending("createdAt");
```

I don't get the attribute `idUSer` in any object. I even added `query.include("idUser");` but still the same output.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the class name and not the column name like:

```
query.include(Parse.User);
```

Comment: it still shows the same results. Didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

When using `ParseRelation`, you will have to use a separate query on the relation field of each object:

```
var anArticle = yourArticles[index];
var userRelationQuery = anArticle.relation("idUser").query();
userRelationQuery.find(......);
```

However, if the `idUser` field is not many-to-many in nature with the article, you could just use a pointer to the user in that field and use `.include()` to fetch the users with your initial query.

Comment: I have tried that aswell. All it says is the result undefined. like there's no relation called `idUser`